# Can a runnable be preempted during its execution on AUTOSAR or OSEK?

Tags: runnable, preemption, autosar

In Autosar, runnables are mapped to tasks. Tasks can be preempted due to the priority.

Where is the point of preemption? Does the preemption happen between runnables?

Is a runnable atomic execution or it can be preempted during its execution?

Answer (score 1):

The point of preemption is to ensure other tasks run at their scheduled intervals.

Since runnables run within the context of a task, and tasks can be preempted, this means that runnables themselves can be preempted. Another consequence is that runnables can only be preempted by runnables in other tasks (or interrupts). So if you have runnables A and B running in the same task, then A will never be preempted by B and vice versa - A and B are atomic with respect to one another.

Autosar further supports *exclusive areas*, a mechanism that is essentially a critical section. Multiple runnables can use the same exclusive area, and if one runnable enters an exclusive area with `Rte_Enter` then no other runnable can enter the same exclusive area until the first one leaves it with `Rte_Exit`.

Comment: In the latest AUTOSAR standards Specification of RTE V4.4.0 technical terms section, there is a term preemption area: A preemption area defines a set of tasks which are scheduled cooperatively. Therefore tasks of one preemption area are preempting each other only at dedicated schedule points. A schedule point is not allowed to occur during the execution of a RunnableEntity. Does this mean a runnable can not be preempted or the preemption of runnable is not allowed by AUTOSAR?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer , i would like to add the concept called Cooperative runnable placement in Autosar. According to the concept the runnbles which has constraints of data access are grouped as "**Cooperative Runnables**" where runnables in this group will never preempt each other, But can be preempted by runnables which are not belongs to this group.

Also runnables are executed in the context of task, if the task is preemptable then runnables belongs to the task are also preemptable.

Comment: I can find "Cooperative Runnable placement strategy" in AUTOSAR standards Specification of RTE V2.3.0. However, it seems this mechanism has been removed from section "Mechanisms to guarantee data consistency" from the latest AUTOSAR standards  Specification of RTE V4.4.0. I am just wondering if there is any similar mechanism in the newest version?